# How does Tim would break the window or How would Tim break the window?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

1. How does Tim would break the window?
2. How would Tim break the window?

Both correct and have the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How does Tim would break the window**?

The sentence is wrong because there are two helping verbs in the sentence: *does* and *would*.

> **How does Tim break the window**?
>   **How would Tim break the window.**?

The above sentences are both correct.

> **How does Tim break the window**?

implies that Tim has the habit of breaking the windows  and we want to know how he does that.

> **How would Tom break the window**?

may talk about a hypothetical future or  the past habit of Tim breaking the window.